# SQL Server - Monitoring request

Tags: sql, sql-server, monitoring

I've a performance problem with an java web application which runs with SQL Server, it seems that sql server is busy and a request which is executed normally in 1 second, take more than 1 hour.
Lot of tools send request on this server and i really don't know how to find where is the problem.

Did you know free monitoring tools for SQL Server (See all request which are running in real time, which request take huge amount...)

Thank's

Answer (score 1):

I'd first take a look at `EXEC sp_who2` to see if you're getting any blocking. If a process is being blocked by another SPID (look in the BlkBy column) then you need to investigate that one further.

Adam Machanic's `sp_whoisactive` is pretty useful to see what's currently going on on your server;

http://whoisactive.com

If you need further in depth tools then the first responder kit from Brent Ozar is pretty good and is a free download. It gives you links to documentation on each different issue if you're not sure on how to fix them.

https://www.brentozar.com/responder/

I'd recommend signing up to a couple of their mailing lists too.